# PHP Excel method overview with description

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

i´m learning the class PHPExcel since yesterday. I found documentations in the zip file and https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Documentation

and here http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel/PHPExcel_Cell.html#methodgetColumn

watch a lot of exampels from the zip file, but it´s very difficult to know all methods and what they mean.

Do somebody know, where i can find a list with methods and description, perhaps with exampels?

regards,
ebody

Comment: Well the second link you've listed gives access to documentation for every class and method in the library....... but there is no documentation provided that gives examples of the use of every single one of those methods..... given how few people bother to read any of the documentation provided, it wouldn't be worth the effort..... every hour spent updating the documentation (that is generally ignored) is an hour that can't be spent working on the library itself

Comment: Yes thats right. I found another documentation [link](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html) which gives more information.